# Installing and running a haskell package offline

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, haskell-platform, duckling

I'm trying to run duckling (https://github.com/facebook/duckling) on a Windows server.

Unfortunately, the server only has intranet access and no internet access. How do I set up Haskell to be able to build and run a package without internet access?

Comment: Can you build your binary on a different machine, and then just copy the binary over? I've done this, building Windows binaries from virtualbox on Linux.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first method that comes to mind is using a same architecture machine that does have internet access to fetch the toolchain and dependencies, before transferring those to the offline build machine. Something like using `stack build --prefetch --install-ghc --dry-run`, then copying the stack tool, stack root, compiler (listed by `stack path`) and your project. I suspect someone has made a better procedure for this.

Some discussion: https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/359 https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/haskell-stack/LHG9DSrz8k8

Another option might be setting up your own mirror of the packages, and pointing stack to those using options like [`latest-snapshot-url`](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/yaml_configuration/#latest-snapshot-url) and `package-indices`. [offline-stack](https://github.com/ndmitchell/offline-stack) appears to collect some steps of this.

Comment: So does same architecture refer to the same CPU architecture (like AVX) or same as in operating system?

Comment: Probably both. Otherwise you'd have to start at bootstrapping the compiler. Might be more along the level of amd64 or x86 rather than specific extensions like AVX, though.